# @ key doesn't work in Excel

Tags: excel, keyboard, excel-2010, symbols

Does anyone know a reason why my **@** key doesn't work in Excel 2010 ? I have a german keyboard (hence I have to press **Alt Gr** + **q**): 
[image: german keyboard layout]

The €(Euro) Key doesn't work either. I have already checked the keyboard layout in the Windows 7 System settings. There is only one layout installed (the german one). In other Programms like Word, the @ key works. So I would guess it is a Excel problem.

Btw: pressing the "Alt Gr" + "q"  button in Excel plays the windows system "default beep (windows ding)" sound.

Meanwhile, as temporary solution, I always copy and paste the **@** symbol from Word to Excel.

Comment: A better 'kludge' might be [alt]+0064 with the digits typed on the numpad.

Answer (score 0):

The at symbol is used to shorten formulas inside named tables referencing cells, perhaps you get an error from trying to use it in a way which does not work

As Microsoft says:

In Office 2010 this notation has been condensed to improve the user experience.  The “[#This Row]” notation has been replaced with an “@” notation in formulas and, where possible, the requirement for explicit table name references in the formula have been removed.

Comment: I'm trying to insert only a @ symbol in an empty cell. So I do not try to use the symbol in any special way.

Comment: all I can think of is using the symbols tab, if you use it regularly it will be your top hit so all you need to press is `Alt - N - U - Enter - Enter - Enter` after using it once.